# Firefox: Having multiple quick search features in one extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to have multiple quick search feature in one extension. However, I do not see any way to create a new one with the same extension.

I have looked around and although there is another post asking this question ([Is it possible to add multiple search engines in the same firefox Web Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304959/is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-search-engines-in-the-same-firefox-web-extension)), it remains unanswered. I have not found anything else regarding this.

What do I need to to get this working?

edit: chrome_settings_overrides code:

```json
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "YouTube",
      "search_url": "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={searchTerms}",
      "favicon_url": "https://www.youtube.com/favicon.ico",

      "keyword": [ "@youtube", "@yt" ]
    }
```